# Validate form cURL request return json response

Tags: php, curl

Hi I'm trying to validate a form using a json output tha I get from a cURL request. 
In my code I first check if the fields are empty or not, then I send the cURL request and I get the following json output if the fields are wrong

```
array(2) { ["errorDetailCode"]=> int(-44) ["errorDetailMessage"]=> string(37) "username or password not found" } 

array(2) { ["errorDetailCode"]=> int(-2) ["errorDetailMessage"]=> string(23) "username not found" }

array(2) { ["errorDetailCode"]=> int(-1) ["errorDetailMessage"]=> string(19) "password not found" }
```

The problem is after it shows the first message username and password not found then it doesn't show the other two messages: username not foundand password not found but still show the message: username or password not found. Do you know why? Ths is my code

```
$km_username = filter_var($_POST['userName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$km_user_password = $_POST['userPassword'];

// Validate form fields if they are empty
if(empty($km_username) && empty($km_user_password)) {

        // Error message if email and password fields are empty
        $_SESSION['km_error_message'] = 'Insert username and password!';
        header('Location: '.KM_BASE_URL.'/login.php');
        exit();

}else if(empty($km_username)) {

        // Error message if username field is empty
        $_SESSION['km_error_message'] = 'Insert username!';
        header('Location: '.KM_BASE_URL.'/login.php');
        exit();

}else if(empty($km_user_password)) {

        // Error message if password field is empty
        $_SESSION['km_error_message'] = 'Insert password!';
        header('Location: '.KM_BASE_URL.'/login.php');
        exit();

}

// Store form fields into an array
$fields = array(
    'userid' => $km_username,
    'password' => $km_user_password
);

// cURL request to API
$cURL = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, URL_LOGIN_API);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$cURL_response = curl_exec($cURL); // execute the curl command

    if (curl_error($cURL)) {
        echo curl_error($cURL);
    }

curl_close ($cURL);

$json_response = json_decode($cURL_response, true);


// Form validation after cURL request

if(isset($json_response['errorDetailCode'])){

    // Error message if cURL request error
    $_SESSION['km_error_message'] = $json_response['errorDetailMessage'];
    header('Location: '.KM_BASE_URL.'/login.php');
    exit();

}else{

    // Store the cookie file name into the session
    if (!isset($_SESSION['cookiefile'])) {
        $cookiefile = tempnam(".", "cookie");
        $_SESSION['cookiefile'] = basename($cookiefile);
        file_put_contents($cookiefile, "");
    }

    // cURL request to API
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, URL_LOGIN_API);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile); // Cookie aware
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile); // Cookie aware
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // Redirerct user to dashboard
    header('Location: '.KM_BASE_URL.'/client-dashboard.php');
    exit();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it seems to me that you are checking if the decoded array has the key 'errorDetailCode', if the condition is met, send a header and terminate the script.

The message inside the first array you got back from cURL will be sent within the header, but after that there is the exit() call, the script is over, and it can not send or print anything more.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, do I need to remove the exit() call then?

Comment: I think you should join all the messages you want to pass over into one single variable, store it into the session array and then proceed to the redirect and exit call. The exit call ensures your script is terminated after the redirect, it should stay where it is.

Comment: Hi @AndreaGolin could you please show me how to achieve it? Many thanks